# Java Agent XPages: iCal4j TimeZoneRegistry.getTimeZone returns null

Tags: java, xpages, icalendar, ical4j

We have just started using [iCal4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/wiki) for generating iCalendar files. Everything seems to work correctly without the timezone, however, as soon as we try to get the timezone from the registry (no matter what the timezone is), it returns null and hence we are not able to retrieve the VTimeZone.

Here is what we have tried:

```
TimeZoneRegistry registry=TimeZoneRegistryFactory.getInstance().createRegistry();
TimeZone timeZone = registry.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()); // no matter what we pass here, it returns null
if (timeZone == null) { 
    System.out.println("Timezone is null"); 
}else{
    VTimeZone tz=timeZone.getVTimeZone(); //never executed
}
```

Probably we are missing something very small, but not sure what. Any help here would really be appreciated.

Edit 1:

Just imported the very same code on a java project on Eclipse and that seems to work correctly. Can it have something to do with the domino?

Answer (score 0):

ical4j is using various ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() calls to load the VTIMEZONE from the ical4j jar file so if you are in an environment with a custom classloader that does not allow this type of access, things won't work indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I believe I get an error before that. Timezone itself is null when retrieved from the registry. So, I guess call to VTimeZone would never be executed. Though what you say makes sense..can you suggest an alternative?